# Select programmatically column names in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to programmatically access a column in a data.table, which is called "X201804_QTY", but I do not succeed. Maybe someone can help? Thank you.

```
#test data
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(test = 1:10, X201804_QTY = 11:20)

#create column name programmatically
col <-  paste0(make.names(format(as.Date("2018-04-30"), "%Y%m")),"_QTY")  

#not working
data[, .(test, col)]
data[, .(test, col), which = FALSE]
data[, c("test", col)]
data[, c("test", col), which = FALSE]

data.table version: 1.10.4-3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

```
data[, col, with = FALSE]
#           ^^^^
```

not `which`. Also `data[, c("test", col), with = FALSE]` would work, of course.

---

The former successfully yields

```
    X201804_QTY
 1:          11
 2:          12
 3:          13
 4:          14
 5:          15
 6:          16
 7:          17
 8:          18
 9:          19
10:          20
```

Comment: Ok, I think i'll call it a day and go home...Thanks!

Comment: @Sven: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `data.table` version 1.10.2 you no longer need the `with = FALSE` you can use `..` as a shorthand like:

```
data[, ..col]

 #   X201804_QTY
 #1:          11
 #2:          12
 #3:          13
 #4:          14
 #5:          15
 #6:          16
 #7:          17
 #8:          18
 #9:          19
#10:          20
```

To select both `col` and `test` if you are in the development version (1.10.5) you could co:

```
data[,c(..cols, "test")]
```

Otherwise I believe you currently have to do:

```
cols2 <- c(cols, "test")
data[, ..cols2]
```

---

It might be a good idea to consider using this since in the `data.table` news here (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) they say:

> Please change to using the .. prefix and over the next few years we will start to formally deprecate and remove the with= parameter

Comment: Ok. Very useful. I was not aware about. How is it working to select also the test column in this case as data[, ..(test, col)] is not working.

Comment: @Sven, see my update. It depends on if you are using the dev version or not. If you are , it is simple. If you are not, it is unfortunately a little more annoying

Answer (score 1):

This should also do:

```
data[, .SD, .SDcols = c("test", col)]
```